# I just want to pass the list to the asp.net web api using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, api, wep

I'm working on EAV database pattern.
My model is like this:

```
public class LeadsModel
{
    public int? CompId { get; set; }
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
    public string LeadName { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<AttributesModel> AList { get; set; }

}
```

My view is like this. In view I'm fetching the list of attributes and I want to post back the using angularjs.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="At in Attributes" >
                        <label for="{{At.Attri}}" class="col-md-4 control-label">{{At.Attri}}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @*<input type="hidden" name="{{At.AID}}" data-ng-model="newLead.NewAlist" />*@
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{At.Attri}}" name="{{At.Attri}}" pl placeholder="Enter {{At.Attri}}" data-ng-model="newLead.AList.AttriValue" ng-blur="AddItemToList(newLead.Alist.AttriValue)" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My Angular code is like this

```
 $scope.add = function ()
    {
        $scope.loading = true;
        this.newLead.AList = $scope.listt;
        $http.post('/api/Leads/Posttbl_Lead', this.newLead).success(function (data) { 
            alert("Added Successfully!!");
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.addLMode = false;
        })
        .error(function () {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }
```

and my web api controller is like this

```
public IHttpActionResult Posttbl_Lead(LeadsModel tbl_Lead)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        tbl_Lead newLead = new tbl_Lead();
        newLead.LeadName = tbl_Lead.LeadName;
        newLead.source = tbl_Lead.source;
        newLead.status = tbl_Lead.status;
        newLead.LeadName = tbl_Lead.LeadName;
        newLead.CompId = tbl_Lead.CompId;

        db.tbl_Lead.Add(newLead);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = tbl_Lead.LeadID }, tbl_Lead);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to post your **newLead** of AngularJs to **tbl_Lead** of your API contoller. This is the complementary [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042853/posting-array-of-objects-with-mvc-web-api) for You to pass the list/ array object to You API.

```
$http({

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",//required

    method: "POST",

    url: '/api/Leads/Posttbl_Lead',

    dataType: "json",//optional

    data:{ "tbl_Lead": newLead },

    async: "isAsync"//optional

})
  .success( function (response) {

       alert('Saved Successfully.');                    

   })
  .error(function () {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
        $scope.loading = false;
   });
```

**Edit-1**

Below mentioned is the way to send AList inside LeadsModel to your api.

**LeadsModel** to send onto the server via API.

```
{
    CompId=compId,
    LeadID=leadID,
    AList=[{FirstObject=firstObject},{SecondObject=secondObject}]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, how i can send AList with it.

Comment: I'm unable to figure it out what exactly is getting complex for You. In order to sent any list to API it should be in the array format of JSON. I'm editing answer please check it and let me know.