# How to Get json data in a single object while post from Rest Client?

Tags: c#, json, api, web

I have the following json data which i used in RestClient to post.

```
{
  "Cars": [
      {
        "color":"Blue",
        "miles":100,
        "vin":"1234"
      },
      {
        "color":"Red",
        "miles":400,
        "vin":"1235"
      }
  ],
  "truck": {
    "color":"Red",
    "miles":400,
    "vin":"1235"
  }
}
```

and i am trying to get this json in a single object at server side while do post from Rest Client

```
public JsonResult Post([FromBody]Object Cars)
{
    return Cars;
}
```

How can i get this json in a single object?

Comment: Are you interested in only the cars from the JSON, or the entire object?

Comment: i need json in an object from where i can get Cars parameter values like color, miles , vin etc at server side.

Comment: yes i need an entire object.

Comment: If you are passing the same data but a different vehicle type, you may be better passing the vehicle type has a value rather than a property field, like `"type": "car"` or `"type": "truck"` and pass them inside a `"vehicles": []` array

Comment: yes ok..but i m not getting json data in a single object.

Comment: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4)

Comment: @KinjalPatel that uses JSON.net which the op isn't using.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the entire JSON into an object then here I used [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert your JSON into classes.

```
public class Car
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public int miles { get; set; }
    public string vin { get; set; }
}

public class Truck
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public int miles { get; set; }
    public string vin { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public Truck truck { get; set; }
}
```

Change your API to:

```
public JsonResult Post([FromBody]RootObject root)
{
    return root.Cars; // List<Car>
}
```

Now you can access `Cars` and `truck`.

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked many times before: [Posting array of objects with MVC Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042853/posting-array-of-objects-with-mvc-web-api)

You may be better using a class to represent the object

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string color;
    public string type;
    public int miles;
    public int vin;
}
```

Then you can use that:

```
public JsonResult Post([FromBody]Vehicle[] vehicles)
{
    return vehicles;
}
```

With data like:

```
[
  {
    "color":"Blue",
    "type": "car"
    "miles":100,
    "vin":"1234"
  },
  {
    "color":"Red",
    "type": "car"
    "miles":400,
    "vin":"1235"
  },
  {
    "color":"Red",
    "type": "truck"
    "miles":400,
    "vin":"1235"
  }
]
```